# Can you explain the output of the following source code?

Tags: java, string, substring

As Strings objects are immutable in java then how for this code output is coming `NOW HEAT`, why not `HOW NEAT`?
Thanks in advance.

```
class Solution
{
   public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String[] words = {"HOW", "NEAT"};
        twist(words);
        System.out.println(words[0] + " " + words[1]);   
    }
    public static void twist(String[] w)
    {
         String temp = w[0].substring(0, 1);
         w[0] = w[1].substring(0, 1) + w[0].substring(1);
         w[1] = temp + w[1].substring(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Run it in an IDE...

Comment: use a Debugger and find it out

Comment: The strings ARE immutable.  You created new ones from the originals.

Comment: @ryekayo,i have ran it on Ide its giving the output NOW HEAT,thats why am i asking why this output is coming.

Comment: The array reference is immutable, but the array it points to is not.  You created new strings and made the array point to them.

Comment: I donn't understand why all of u downvote ,if u donn't want to answer donn't answer at least downvoting is not the solution as i'm new to this ,its led to anyone donn't ask any problem again in future.

Answer (score 1):

Basically what your code is doing is that it is switching the first characters of the both the first letters of each string. Here is a step by step explanation

1. `temp` = 'H'
2. `w[0]` = NOW (temp + "OW")
3. `w[1]` = HEAT (temp + "EAT")

*EDIT*: 
As duffymo said:

> The array reference is immutable, but the array it points to is not. You created new strings and made the array point to them.

This means everytime you reassigned, you created a new string.

Comment: i have understood the code,i'm not asking u what is happening in the code ,i  am just asking if strings are immutable how the replacement is taking place.For this u can downvote me also thanks in advance for downvoting.